# Nearby location in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to show Merchant details approximately 60 miles distance through the User current location,

Below My coding,

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = '*,   ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $currentlatval . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) '
            . '* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $currentlngval . ') ) '
            . '+ sin( radians(' . $currentlatval . ') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance ';
    $criteria->having = ("distance < 60");
    $criteria->group = 'uid';
    $results2 = Merchant::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Its Working Properly,In the above code it check only attribute lat and lng,But I want to also check attribute city_lat and city_lng in above code How to write to check both attribute?

Comment: What do you mean for "I want to also check attribute city_lat and city_lng" please explain or show an examples

Comment: Now check  lng ,lat But  i want to also check attribute city_lat and city_lng field in DB cos( radians( lng ) cos( radians( city_lng )